# algorithm to find minimum steps to finish a path

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic

the problem is to move a player along a path
of n squares, starting at square 1 and moving forward at each step. At any
point, you can do one of three things.

- press white button to move forward 2 squares. If 
  there fewer than 2 squares left, then this button terminates
  the game and you win.
- press red button to move forward 3 squares. If 
  there fewer than 3 squares left, then this button terminates
  the game and you win.
- press green button to move forward 5 squares. If 
  there fewer than 5 squares left, then this button terminates
  the game and you win.

rules: each square is painted either with blue and green.
if the player stop on a green square. the he lose.

how to design algorithm to find:

1. minimum steps needed to finish the game
2. buttons needed to be pressed in order to win.

Comment: What is the specific problem you bump into? Could you show your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You can work backwards from the end and apply a dynamic programming algorithm:

Start with the last entry in the path:

- If it is blue:

  - If there are fewer than 5 places after this one: link a green move (5 steps) to that entry
  - Else check each of the spots that are 2, 3 and 5 ahead in the path (which were already processed): take the one that has the best solution (fewest moves) linked to it. Extend (prepend) that solution with the corresponding move (2 = white, 3 = ... etc) and store that information in the current entry.

Repeat this for each preceding entry in the path, each time storing the information of the shortest path from there to a win (if it is blue)

The solution is what has been stored in the first entry of the path. Of course, there are situations where there is no win possible.